# How to generate Fibonacci series?

Tags: vb.net

I am a beginner for programming and dealing with concept of visual basic 2010 to generate the following Fibonacci series output that will get the next number by adding two consecutive numbers

I have tried that by creating variables like bellow

```
Public Class Form1
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim b As Integer = 1
    Dim fib As Integer = 0

    Do
      fib = a + b
      a = b
      b = fib
      Label1.Text = Label1.Text + fib.ToString & ControlChars.NewLine
    Loop While fib < 55
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: What have you tried? Look at using a loop and one variable to store the last number operated on.

Comment: First, what is the fibonacci equation? Once you get that down, it won't be so hard to code up.

Comment: You suggested me fine! thanks I will study in detail it. thanks.

Comment: did you try the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
 Dim a As Integer = 0
    Dim b As Integer = 1
    Dim fib As Integer 

    Do
        Label1.Text += a.ToString & ControlChars.NewLine
        fib = a + b
        a = b
        b = fib
    Loop While a <= 55
```

Comment: for the community purpose that is more helpful to understand and use it. But also your answer is helpful

Comment: A GUI interface doesn't make it a better answer. Still I'm glad I could help.

Comment: @OrvillePatterson the accepted answer allows for calculation of Fib(n), while this only calculates Fib(55).

Comment: Now I included and suggested what I tried. please vote me up once

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Dim x, g, n, i, sum As Integer
n = Val(Text1.Text)
x = 0
y = 1
Print x
Print y
For i = 3 To n
sum = x + y
Print sum
x = y
y = sum
y = sum
Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: please can u help me to vote up once the this suggested question.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution:

```
Dim num1 As Integer = 1
Dim num2 As Integer = 1
Dim aux As Integer

Console.Write(num1)
Console.Write(", ")
Console.Write(num2)
Console.Write(", ")

While num1 < 100
   aux = num1 + num2
   Console.Write(aux)
   Console.Write(", ")
   num1 = num2
   num2 = aux
End While
```

This print Fibonacci series till number 100

I hope this help you!